# Remove row from results under when statement

Tags: sql, ssms

```
WHEN Q.ProgramTitle IN ('Therapeutic Massage AOS','Therapeutic Massage','Therapeutic Massage OAD','Therapeutic Massage (h)','Therapeutic Massage OAD') AND max(M.OPEID) IN ('031151-02') then '11'
 WHEN Q.ProgramTitle IN ('X-Ray Medical Technician','X-Ray Medical Technician AOS','X-Ray Medical Technician*') AND max(M.OPEID) IN ('031151-02') then '14'
WHEN Q.ProgramTitle = 'Surgical Technology' AND max(M.OPEID) IN ('031151-00') then '15'
WHEN Q.ProgramTitle = 'Emergency medical Technician' 
end
'Length of GE Program',
```

Okay, so I need to remove all rows that contain the program name 'Emergency medical technician' under my WHEN statement, but I have no idea how to code that. Suggestions?

Comment: give us some sample code, perhaps markdown from a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @sqlfiddle edited above. just need to tell sql to remove rows that have that program name (line not finished above).

Comment: "not finished" means we don't have enough to work with to confidently provide an answer. but why not just leave the 'EMT' title out of your WHEN clause and put a <> 'EMT' in your WHERE instead? That, after all, is the fundamental concept of how to exclude rows from result sets.

Comment: @underscore_d that's exactly what I needed to see! I didn't know what the 'does not equal' sign was. thanks for you help!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you might also see `!=` used in some dialects of SQL including T-SQL (and other languages), where it acts equivalently. However, the ANSI standard operator is `<>`, so that's most likely to work across the most different database engines.